# On error event for img. Any way to get error description

Tags: javascript, html

Is there any way to get a description about the error when img.onerror is rised ? 
I'm using img.src = ....
I can catch the error, but  I'd like to know more about the error.

The event received does not give any kind of information.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

**Some** Browsers do not support onerror. Here is the best method for catching your stacktrace universally.

```
function wrap(func) {
// Ensure we only wrap the function once.
if (!func._wrapped) {
    func._wrapped = function () {
        try{
            func.apply(this, arguments);
        } catch(e) {
            console.log(e.message, "from", e.stack);
            throw e;
        }
    }
}
return func._wrapped;
};
```

If you want to continue using onerror. Use an event listener.

```
window.addEventListener("error", function (e) {
console.log(e.error.message, "from", e.error.stack);
});
```